# Draw/Render Text over a DirectX Video (PictureBox Control as Owner)

Tags: c#, winforms, directx

I have managed to implement a video playing capability to my WinForms Application Project using DirectX's Video Class (although old and deprecated). My goal was to use this video as a background for a specific form with minimal controls. I've tried using GIF files but the color quality is just not good enough, using APNG on the other hand leaves me with a hilariously large .apng file size.

As Dx's Video Class needs a control to play the video into - i've used a PictureBox Control to make do where a Panel Control can also substitute for this. My Next Goal is to draw/render a text over the PictureBox Control which acts as the host for the Video. This is due to that Label Controls are not transparent nor does it support transparency in 100% so i am trying to improvise by rendering a string using `Graphics.DrawString()` or `TextRenderer.DrawText()`.

I've tried both but neither was able to display the text as i've expected it to be.

Below is my code snippet over the `Paint Event` for the PictureBox Control:

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
     var font = new Font("Helvetica Neue LT Std 65", 15);
     var brush = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
     var point = new Point(55, 150);

     string welcomeText = "Welcome, User!";

     // e.Graphics.DrawString(welcomeText, font, brush, point);

     TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, welcomeText, font, point, Color.White);

     pictureBox1.Refresh();
}
```

when running my source code, nothing happens actually, just like in this GIF: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fguP.jpg

however, what i'm expecting is something like this:
[image]

Is it even possible to achieve this in the first place with WinForms? If so, i'd like some help to implement this. Thank you.

Comment: Without the video playing does it work? Like the text isn't under the video? Whats the `Refresh` for? Have you tried a transparent TextBox (thats read-only without borders) http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4390/AlphaBlendTextBox-A-transparent-translucent-textbo ?

Comment: Same comment on the `pictureBox1.Refresh();` inside a `Paint()` event. `var font` and `var brush` also don't belong and leak, use private fields. Same for `var point` and `string welcomeText`, they're always the same. If `e.Graphics` can't draw on the Picture, you could use an Overlay. Build a Class derived from Form and make it Transparent. Draw the string in its Paint() event. This works with VLC Player. Not sure with DirectX on a PictureBox (never tested). You should probably move to WPF.

Comment: @JeremyThompson i've read somewhere that there are some cases that anything drawn may night appear and was advised to use `.Refresh()` for changes to appear. And yes, without Dx's Video, the string gets rendered over the control. i've tried using TextBox but it doesn't support transparent background color.

Comment: @Jimi all those variables were placed there for testing purposes but i'll take note about the `don't belong and leak` part for further coding references. i don't have any experience with deriving a class from form and making it transparent. maybe the best way really is moving to WPF.

Comment: Comments are directed to the code presented, not to the author (you, of course, may have your reasons, like in this case, you're just testing). Someone else, reading a comment, can get something out of it. Anyway, since you're using DirectX (and I won't ask you why :), you will probably find it much easier in WPF. You can overlay mostly anything on anything there. Also, see [MediaPlayer Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.mediaplayer(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Try overlaying a 2nd form.

Comment: Can you please give us a [mcve]?